# Where to store location data, which changes every second, for remote access

Tags: python, hosting, cpanel

Hello there, hope you are all doing well.

I have a Python script on my Android device which acquires location data (latitude and longitude) every seconds. I want this changing data to be available to few other peoples as well. They need to get the exact location of the device every seconds, from a Python script. I have a cPanel host which I believe I can use, however, I have no prior experience and I need to find the simplest way for that. In short, I have cPanel host which I can use the store the instant data. However, I do not know how to configure the cPanel to store data. After configuration, which Python module should I use to send the data to the web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend uploading that data to an SQL database. You haven't shared your code so I can't provide an accurate example but you should do something like this in your python script:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

# database connection
try:
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost', database='coordinates_db', user='****', password='****')
except Error as e:
    print(e)

cursor = conn.cursor()


# Latitude and Longitude example coordinates
Latitude = '-27.51757'
Longitude =  '49.66617'


# Insert coordinates to database
insert_query = f'INSERT INTO coordinates (Latitude, Longitude) VALUES ("{Latitude}, {Longitude}");'
cursor.execute(insert_query)
conn.commit()
```

This should be the SQL:

```
/* Execute this line block to create a coordinates table */
create table coordinates(
id int auto_increment primary key,
Latitude varchar(100),
Longitude varchar(100)
);

/* Execute this line block to view coordinates table */
Select * from coordinates;
```

You will of course have to replace the database configuration in the python file with your own database configuration which you can find in your cpanel.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! Will check the code and your suggestions very soon!